# How to get rid of Unity 2d's task bar notifications?

Tags: unity-2d, notification

When an IM or (other program) gets a new message, it flashes its window and I my Unity left bar opens itself and grabs my attention. The animation takes around five seconds and bugs me.

Is there a way I can prevent the left bar to show itself and grab my attention?

He're is how it looks
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gCuP.png]

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu with Unity 3D only :**

Install CCSM from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Launch `ccsm` from Dash or terminal.

Go to **Desktop → Ubuntu Unity Plugin → Experimental → Launch Animation** and **Urgent Animation** and set both to **None**.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a solution. However I tried it, and I still get animation. 

Maybe its because I seem to be running 2D unity, even though I choosed 3D on login screen just now to be sure. MyUnity still says I am using a 2D version. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Type `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` in a terminal to be sure of what you're running: ubuntu-2d or ubuntu (3D). If it's 2D, I can't help you but you should add a **Unity 2D** tag to the question.

Comment: I am running 2D, but I guess people running 3D can use this answer, so I mark it accepted.

Comment: You could upvote it instead of accepting it. Someone may have an answer for 2D.

Comment: Okay, if you don't mind, then I can. But I will only be able to upvote it once I reach reputation of 15.